# Html code to display featured image caption

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-featured-image

I'm using the Hello Elementor theme with Wordpress, and featured image is not displayed in posts. You have to get the pro version for that.
So I've downloaded the "Shortcoder" plugin, and created a shortcode with the following code:

```
<img src="$$post_image$$" alt="$$title$$" />
```

This displays the image fine on the post, when I include the shortcode.

However, I would also like to include the caption for the image.
Can you help with this?

The shortcoder plugin does not support php code...

Thanks.

Best regards,
Thomas